# Flex tree expand slowly/lazy loading when there are more than 30000 nodes

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, lazy-loading, flex4.5

I want to open all nodes of Flex mx Tree in such a way that UI is responsive at all times. Normally when there are limited no of nodes then this code works just fine.

```
public function expandAllNodes():void {
  for (var i:int = 0; i < this.dataProvider.length; i++) {
    expandChildrenOf(this.dataProvider.getItemAt(i), true);
  }
}
```

maybe i need to callLater instead of directly calling the function

```
public function expandAllNodes():void {
  for (var i:int = 0; i < this.dataProvider.length; i++) {
    calllater(expandChildrenOf,[this.dataProvider.getItemAt(i), true]);
  }
}
```

but this is not working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using callLater won't help in this case.  From the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7b06.html),

> The callLater method queues an operation to be performed for the next screen refresh, rather than in the current update.

Using callLater in your loop will simply push *all* the expandChildrenOf() calls to the next screen refresh -- which will still put way too much work into a single update cycle.

Instead, you could spread your loop over several frames and limit work done per frame:

```
private var processingLimit:int = 10; //experiment to get a reasonable value for this
private var totalNodes:int = 0;
private var nodesProcessed:int = 0;

public function expandAllNodes():void {
    this.totalNodes = this.dataProvider.length;
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, expandNextNode);
}

private function expandNextNode(e:Event):void {
    var numToProcess = Math.min(processingLimit + nodesProcessed, totalNodes);
    for (var i:int = nodesProcessed; i < numToProcess; i++) {
        nodesProcessed++;
        expandChildrenOf(this.dataProvider.getItemAt(i), true);
    }

    if (numToProcess == totalNodes) {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, expandNextNode);
    }
}
```

n.b. Make sure that `expandChildrenOf` doesn't recursively open children of children -- if it does, then you could still end up expanding the entire tree based on a single call to `expandChildrenOf(1);`!

Comment: Should it be **Math.min** instead of **Math.max** ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved the issue

```
private const PROCESSING_LIMIT:int = 25; 
public var _expandNodesStack:Vector.<Object>;
private function expandNextNode(e:Event):void {
  for (var i:int = 0; i < PROCESSING_LIMIT; i++) {
    var item:* = _expandNodesStack.pop();
    if (item)
      expandItem(item, true);
    else
      break;
  }
  if (_expandNodesStack.length == 0) {
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, expandNextNode);
  }
}



public function expandAllNodes():void {
  if(this.dataProvider == null || this.dataProvider.length <= 0) return;
  if (_expandNodesStack != null && _expandNodesStack.length > 0) {
    //already expanding so abort this operation
    return;
  }
  if (_expandNodesStack == null) _expandNodesStack = new <Object>[];
  iterateAndPushToStack(this.dataProvider.getItemAt(0));
  _expandNodesStack.reverse();

  this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, expandNextNode);
}

private function iterateAndPushToStack(item:Object):void {
  if (iterator == null)
    return;

  // if it is not a branch item there's nothing to do
  if (item != null && item.children is ArrayCollection && item.children.length > 0) {
    _expandNodesStack.push(item);
    var childItems:ArrayCollection;
    childItems = item.children;
    if (childItems) {
      for each (var object:Object in childItems) {
        iterateAndPushToStack(object);
      }
    }
  }
}
```